# Molecular dynamics method to simulate a simple fluid

Tags: molecular-dynamics, molecular-modeling, 2d-lattice, fluid-dynamics

I need to implement the molecular dynamics method to simulate a simple fluid that interacts through the Lennard-Jones potential in a 2D simulation. The idea is to explore how the total energy of the system (kinetic + potential) and the particle trajectories depend on the size of the chosen time step.

I took a piece of code that does part of the job(I will upload it here) but I would like a algorithm to helpe-me to finish. I  will try to summarize what I understood until now:

1. Initially it sets the physical parameters and parameters of simulation

- temperature
- density
- number of particles
- size of the box
- Lennard-Jones cut-radius
- Verlet-list radius

2. It initializes the vectors and lattice

- position and velocity vectors x,y and vx,vy
- distributes the particles in a square centered lattice
- Chooses velocities uniformly on a unit circle
- Normalizes the velocities according to the energy equipartition
  theore
- make the total momentum of the particles equal to zero

3. Creates a verlet list to define neighbors

My doubts are:

How and when to use Lennard Jones potential and Verlet Velocities in the code ?
Does someone have an example algorithm or can put it in a manner that I can follow the steps?

The code until now:
[MolecularDynamics_2DfluidSimulation](https://github.com/danielrflor/public/blob/e5e0b05373a820b5e36b34f385136c906b1b6ec6/2D-MolecularDynamics.ipynb)

Comment: "Computer Simulation of Liquids" by Allen and Tildesley. The book contains FORTRAN and Python examples (https://github.com/Allen-Tildesley/examples/tree/master/python_examples) for various kinds of simulation exercises. This would be the best reference for your project.

Comment: Hey that's my line @Magic_Number

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [comment by Magic_Number](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/9814/molecular-dynamics-method-to-simulate-a-simple-fluid#comment20691_9814) and the [comment by B. Kelly](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/9814/molecular-dynamics-method-to-simulate-a-simple-fluid#comment20699_9814), and the lack of response, and the OP not signing in for the last 7 months, I'll assume that it's enough to say that [this link](https://github.com/Allen-Tildesley/examples/tree/master/python_examples) provided by Magic_Number has the required code, and I'll say that this Community Wiki post can be deleted if someone wants to write a more detailed answer.